# PHP: Convert a cookie domain for a subdomain

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

My actual situation

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/project1
```

For this i use this session configuration
(the session must be active for up to one hour, and be valid only on the folder **/project1**)

```
$lifetime = 3600;
session_start();
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$lifetime,"/project1");
```

Soon i'll have to move the /project1 in a subdomain

```
http://project1.stackoverflow.com
```

How do i change the session to be valid only in the subdomain **project1** ?
thanks

Comment: If your run your cookie creation logic from your subdomain, the cookie will be created/valid for that subdomain. Can you try executing from subdomain ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you stop managing the Session cookie manually like this, and let PHP handle it automatically for you.

You can set the path, domain, expiry etc for the session cookie with the function [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params)

Comment: I used setcookie instead of session_set_cookie_params for a problem relative to session lifetimes. see http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params#100657

Comment: You can solve that problem by running `session_regenerate_id(true);` on each request - it will create a new session ID + cookie automatically, preventing the old one from expiring.